# Получаю json с другого сервера на php

Tags: php, json

Не могу никак получить данные в формате json.

```
 $fp = @fsockopen("example.ru", 81, $errno, $errstr, 30);
        if (!$fp) {
            return;
        }else {
            $pknum = 1470;

            $data = urlencode($pknum);

            $out = "GET /api/api/GetPassport?CompNum=$data\r\n";
            $out .= "Host: example.ru\r\n";
            $out .= "Content-type: json; charset=utf-8\r\n";
            $out .= "Content-length: ".strlen($data)."\r\n";
            $out .= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";
            $out .= $data."\r\n\r\n";

            fwrite($fp, $out);
            while (!feof($fp)) {

                $json.= fgets($fp, 128);
            }
            fclose($fp);

            $jsin = json_decode($json);
 echo $json;  

 echo $jsin[1];
```

Вот что выводит мне $json

```
[{"TypeName":"Case","Condition":"Minitower INWIN EMR002 Micro ATX 350W"},{"TypeName":"Motherboard","Condition":"GigaByte GA-H55M-UD2H (RTL) LGA1156 2xPCI-E"},{"TypeName":"CPU","Condition":"CPU Intel Core i3-540 {3.06ГГц, 2x256КБ+4МБ, EM64T"},{"TypeName":"Memory","Condition":"Samsung DDR-III 2 gb (PC3-10600) 1333MHz"},{"TypeName":"HDD","Condition":"SATA 500 gb WD Caviar Blue (WD5000AAKX)"},{"TypeName":"CD","Condition":"DVD±R/RW & CDRW Optiarc AD-7261S SATA (OEM)"},{"TypeName":"Video","Condition":"встроена"},{"TypeName":"Monitor","Condition":"LCD LG 20\" W2043S-PF, Black {1600x900,300,30000:1"},{"TypeName":"Keyboard","Condition":"Genius KB-06X2 Black 107КЛ"},{"TypeName":"Mouse","Condition":"Genius NetScroll 100 Optical (RTL) USB 3btn+Roll +коврик"},{"TypeName":"Sound card","Condition":"встроена"},{"TypeName":"Net card","Condition":"встроена"},{"TypeName":"Сетевой фильтр","Condition":"Сетевой фильтр SVEN Optima Base Black <3м> ( 5 розеток)"},{"TypeName":"Video","Condition":"GeForce 7600Series DDR2 256Mb Dual DVI"}]
```

Соответственно, `$jsin` ничего не выводит. Пробовал и `decode` и `encode`. Бесполезно, не могу никак сделать json объект и все.

Comment: То, что выводит, очень похоже на json. А вы что ждете?

Answer (score 3):

### Офтоп

1. Не используйте никогда `@`, потом очень сложно отловить ошибку. Лучше сразу нормально обрабатывайте некорректное поведение скрипта.
2. Заголовок `Content-type` вообще то нужен для передачи тела ответа, вам он в запросе не к чему. Для передачи запроса на желаемый формат ответа нужен заголовок `Accept`. И еще `mime type` у вас не правильный, должен быть такой – `Accept: application/json;`.
3. Для указания желаемой кодировки нужен заголовок `Accept-Charset: UTF-8`.
4. Передача тела в гет запросе противоречит спецификации `HTTP`.
5. Для запросов я бы вам посоветовал использовать библиотеку [cUrl](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.curl.php), с ней ваши волосы станут мягкими и шелковистыми.
6. Смотрите кодировку присылаемую сервером в заголовках ответа, и если она отличается от вашей, перекодируйте с помощью например [iconv()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.iconv.php).
7. Если функция `json_decode()` возвращает `null`, значит `json` не валидный. Цитата из русской документации:

> **Возвращаемые значения**
>
> Возвращает данные json преобразованные в
>   соответствующие типы PHP. Значения true, false и null возвращаются как
>   TRUE, FALSE и NULL соответственно. NULL также возвращается, если json
>   не может быть преобразован или закодированные данные содержат
>   вложенных уровней больше, чем допустимый предел для рекурсий.

Answer (score 1):

Сделайте `print_r($jsin)` - увидите всю структуру в массиве. А элемент `$jsin[1]` содержит в себе объект, который обычный `print` напечатать не может. Вообще попытка печати объекта должна вызывать фатальную ошибку, которую ваш скрипт вам почему то не показывает. При этом к конкретным элементам обращаться можно `print($jsin[1]->TypeName)` должен отработать штатно.

Если этого не происходит, убедитесь, что полученный json в кодировке UTF-8, с другими кодировками `json_decode` работать не умеет.

Comment: var_dump($jsin) показывает null.

Comment: Странно, но у меня var_dump на минимальном примере работает с вашим json. Убедитесь, что json у вас в UTF-8 кодировке.

Comment: @Михаил Только что провел тест, загнал ваш json в код в cp1251 кодировке и как я и ожидал, json_decode не смог его разобрать, он умеет работать только с валидным utf-8 json'ом

Comment: Всем спасибо обнаружил. В нескольких элементах лишние "{" фигурные скобки. Так это все из БД берется видимо проще получать xml с сервера и обробатывать его.